# I want to animate several objects consisting of standalone details, when I do ctrl J, it changes materials and a bit geometry, is there a better way?

Tags: objects, transforms

Is there a convenient way to control the complex object without joining parts together?

Comment: There are convenient ways, but which is appropriate depends on how you want to animate the stand alone details.  Please add some more detail to your question so we can focus on the one that's most appropriate in our answers.

Comment: well lets say its a sort of riffle consisting of multiple small details, so I basically need to rotate it and move to showcase the render, and then the humanoid character would handle it, so it will also move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

add an empty.  parent each of the object to the empty, preserving transforms.  to move or rotate the whole thing at once, manipulate the empty.  You can still move or rotate the individual pieces.  They'll stay in the new relative position when you next move the empty.

Here's another:

Create an armature.  Add one bone for each object you want to manipulate. Parent each object to its respective bone.  Manipulate the armature in pose mode to manipulate the parts, move or rotate the armature in object move to move or rotate the whole thing.

Comment: thank you very much, both are useful methods, I feel stupid that I didn`t think of Empty